# Images from seeds.rb don't work on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I have `seeds.rb` file like this (I use paperclip gem):

```
player1 = Player.create(
                        firstname: "John", lastname: "Malkon", nickname: "jonmal",
                        avatar: File.new("#{Rails.root}/public/examples/avatars/1.png"))
```

When I run locally `rake db:seed` everything works (images work fine).

But when I run `heroku run rake db:seed` images don't work.

In the html code I can see:

```
<img src="/system/players/avatars/000/000/007/medium/7.jpg?1438851753" alt="7">
```

But image is broken.

What is the problem (I suppose the problem is about path but I don't kton how to fix it)?

I have my image files in `public/examples/avatars/`

In browser console I get:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found  - http://foosballtr.herokuapp.com/system/players/avatars/000/000/007/medium/7.jpg?1438851753"
```

Where should I put my image files?

Comment: Have precompile assets file? bundle exec rake assets:precompile

Answer (score 4):

I assume a `paperclip` gem takes your image from `public/examples/avatars/` and places it to the `public/system/players/avatars/` directory.

You can't see your images because, the `Heroku` file system is read-only (except `/tmp`), hence your images is not persisted.

See the topic [here](https://discussion.heroku.com/t/write-files-in-heroku/565) for more info on this limitation.

[`Uploading Files to S3 in Ruby with Paperclip`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3)